# How to receive ZMQ message inside Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, zeromq

I want to send ZMQ message inside app.get but when running I throw error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

My running code:

```
var zmq = require('zmq'),
zreq = zmq.socket('req'),
app = express();

zreq.connect('tcp://localhost:5559');

zreq.on('message', function (msg) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.send(msg);
});

app.get('/words', function (req, res) {
    zreq.send('nodejs');
    //I think it should have something like zreqCallback(req)?
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, as the error indicates, that you don't have access to the `res` object from the `message` event handler on your `req` socket. What you need is a way to link the message in that event handler to your `res` object. You're not going to be able to do that (easily) without support from the other end of that socket.

The basic idea is to associate a unique id with each message you send over `zmq` and include it in the message sent through the `req` socket and the reply that comes back from the `rep` socket. Then also associate the `res` object with the same message id.

I usually use [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) for unique id generation. You'll also need a way to easily encode / decode your messages (it looks like you're just sending straight strings at the moment). The built in `JSON` parser works fine for that, or you could use something more compact like [bencode](https://github.com/themasch/node-bencode/) or [protobuf](https://github.com/fuwaneko/node-protobuf). *Be sure to pick something that both ends of the socket can work with.*

**You're code would look something like this:**

***Note:** I'm assuming we're using `node-uuid` and `JSON`. Also, I'm not putting any error handling or sanity checks in here; **don't forget that stuff**.*

```
var zmq = require('zmq'),
uuid = require('node-uuid'),
zreq = zmq.socket('req'),
app = express();

var responses = {};

zreq.connect('tcp://localhost:5559');

zreq.on('message', function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var msgId = data.id;
    var res = responses[msgId];
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.send(data.message);
    responses[msgId] = null;
});

app.get('/words', function (req, res) {
    var msgId = uuid.v4();
    var data = { id: msgId, message: 'nodejs' };
    responses[msgId] = res;
    zreq.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

On the other end (I'll just assume it's also written in node for the purpose of this example):

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
zrep = zmq.socket('rep');

zrep.bind('tcp://localhost:5559');

zrep.on('message', function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var msgId = data.id;
    var msg = data.message;

    // Do whatever you were doing before to process the message
    // We'll say it ends up in a "results" variable

    var response = { id: msgId, message: results };
    zrep.send(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Comment: I'm curious why this got down voted... Did I miss an easier solution somewhere or not explain things well?

Comment: See https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/48 for a discussion. This approach (or similar) seems to be the only way to make it work. Also some sort of messageId is required for DEALER/ROUTER pairs which you are more likely to be using with node.js anyway.